# Load Interstitial Ad on App start in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, admob

I'm a newbie in Android Studio, I made this much progress (There's also coding for webview that I skipped) after reading on Google Developer help section but now I want to load as the app starts as this is the javascript of my home page.

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "APP+ID");

        InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("AD_ID");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    } 
}
```

Comment: You have hard coded the values `APP+ID` and `AD_ID`. If its only for test purposes, you should use the sample units provided by Google - https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads . If its for real production you need to create an admob account and add an app, refer to https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start to help you get started

Comment: Zoe Sorry I didn't knew...Will take care next time!! Bryan Yeah it was just to show how I've coded, in real I've placed the IDs!!!

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your `onCreate`

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
});
```

in your code you are just loading the add but not showing it.

Comment: Yeah I placed it just below "mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());"...Will it work fine now after I complete my project??